# Azure Log Analytics - How to view logs from last x days but only between certain hours?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, azure-application-gateway, kql

I'd like to look at the app gateway 500 error logs over the last x number of days. But for those x number of days, I'd only like to see the logs that came in between 11:00 and 13:00 UTC. How can I do this? Here's what I have so far but it's not working.

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where TimeGenerated > ago(7d) and TimeGenerated between (datetime(11:00:00) .. datetime(13:00:00))
| where ResourceType == "APPLICATIONGATEWAYS" and httpStatus_d > 499
| where host_s == "my.website.com"
| summarize count() by clientIP_s, bin(TimeGenerated, 5m)
```

Obviously the second like (Timegenerated) is wrong. Can someone please advise on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `hourofday()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/hourofdayfunction

For example:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where TimeGenerated > ago(7d)
| where hourofday(TimeGenerated) between (11 .. 12) // 11:00 AM -> 12:59 PM
| where host_s == "my.website.com"
| where ResourceType == "APPLICATIONGATEWAYS"
| where httpStatus_d > 499
| summarize count() by clientIP_s, bin(TimeGenerated, 5m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either your datetime constructors were missing quotes or the KQL API has changed since you first tried.

The following worked for me this morning trying to parse out a specific event:

```
http_event_CL 
| where TimeGenerated between (
    (datetime('2023-12-29 08:00:00')) .. 
    (datetime('2023-12-30 08:05:00'))
  )
```

Here's closer to what I used which converts from local time to UTC:

```
http_event_CL 
| where TimeGenerated between (
    datetime_local_to_utc(datetime('2023-12-29 08:00:00'), 'EST') .. 
    datetime_local_to_utc(datetime('2023-12-30 08:05:00'), 'EST')
  )
```